# How to select an index containing specific characters?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

[cov_afro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1yVT.png)

My goal is to plot the evolution of new covid 19 cases during april in Africa (WHO_region = AFRO). In order to do that, I create the following pivot table:

```
cov_afro_tab = cov_afro.pivot_table('New_cases', index='Date_reported', aggfunc= "sum")
```

[cov_afro_tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tQGp.png)

How can I filter index containing only "2022-04"?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please describe the dataframes using text, rather than an [image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Also, please describe what you've tried so far in the form of an edit to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the index to datetime type and check if the year and month is equal to threshold.

```py
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df_ = df[df.index.strftime('%Y-%m') == '2022-04']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry for the late reply...